# Javascript how to split plain text html elements into an array?

Tags: javascript, html, plaintext

If I have a string containing html elements, what would be an efficient way of creating an array of the sibling html elements?

Trying to use indexOf with the first letter of the opening tag " <" and the last one of the closing tag becomes complicated since there can be child elements.

Simple example:

```
<p>Hello there</p>

<h1>Thank you</h1>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using regex with js split method we can extract.

Check my code

```
let a = `<p>Hello there</p><p>How r you?</p>

<h1>Thank you</h1>`
let b = a.split(/<[a-zA-Z0-9]*>([^<.*>;]*)<\/[a-zA-Z0-9]*>/gmi).filter(x=>x.trim() !== '')
console.log(b) //['Hello there', 'How r you?', 'Thank you']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're trying to do.

```
  <div id="container">
    <div>child 1</div> 
    <div>child 2</div> 
    <div>child 3</div> 
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      let elements = [], container = document.getElementById("container");
      for(let i = 0; i < container.children.length; i++){
          elements.push(container.children[i].outerHTML);
      }
      console.log(elements);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you my friend, but the html elements are in plain text, I they are not dom elements still appreciate your effort

Comment: Ah, now I see what you meant by "a string containing html elements."  :)  Glad Arshpreet's answer seemed to work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to solve this.

Find all the opening and closing tag using regex and replace with "/" (something else) then split it and then filter the ("") using filter(Boolean)

Code:

```js
var elements = [],container = document.getElementById("container");
  for(let i = 0; i < container.children.length; i++)    {                     elements.push(container.children[i].outerHTML.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, ""));
   }
   
      console.log("plainTextArray = ",elements);




let bodyHtml = document.getElementsByTagName('div')["0"].innerHTML;

let plainTextArray = bodyHtml.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "//").split("//").filter(Boolean)

console.log('plainTextArray = ',plainTextArray);
```

```html
<body>
<div id="container"><p>Hello there</p><h1>Thank you</h1></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much but the elements are in plain text not dom elements but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this to get all the texts from the child elements.

```js
let nodeList = document.getElementById('stack').querySelectorAll('*');
let list = [];
nodeList.forEach(function(val){
 list.push(val.outerHTML)
})
console.log(list);
```

```html
<div id="stack">
 <p>Hello there</p>
 <h1>Thank you</h1>
</div>
```