# Convert string of HTML tags to Array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, regex, string

I'm trying to convert a string of HTML to an array of HTML. For example, I might have a string of arbitrary HTML that looks like this:

`"<div>This</div><h1>Is</h1> <p>A</p> <a href="#">Test</a>"`

(There may or may not be spaces between the tag elements)

I'm trying to convert it into an array that looks like this:

```
["<div>This</div>", "<h1>Is</h1>", "<p>A</p>", "<a href="#">Test</a>"]
```

This is just for displaying the tags as text - I'm not going to use them as HTML elements.

I have looked at this example here, and it **almost** works except it strips the tags from the inner text: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54340630/1282216

I'm looking for a solution that does not involve DOM parsing - if possible.

Any suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Always use a DOMParser to parse HTML strings.

```js
const string = `<div>This</div><h1>Is</h1> <p>A</p> <a href="#">Test</a>`;

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(string, "text/html");
const HTMLArray = [...doc.body.children].map(el => el.outerHTML);

console.log(HTMLArray)
```

- [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)
- [ParentNode.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children)
- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/)
- [Element.outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)

You should [**never use RegExp**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) to parse XML/HTML strings.  But if you really want, and know your string by hearth and looks as you provided it...

```js
const str = `<div>This</div><h1>Is</h1> <p>A</p> <a href="#">Test</a>`;
const m = str.match(/<[^>]+>[^<]*<\/[^>]+>/g); // Use at your own risk

console.log(m);
```

**Notice** that the above will not work for deeply nested HTML, and if inside an attribute there's a `<` or `>` character (which is completely valid and not unusual)

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm actually not parsing real HTML. It's just a string that looks like HTML and is being displayed for presentation purposes (on a WebGL texture).

Comment: @d13 if you don't use nested HTML or XML (the string is exactly as you provided it), you could try the above RegExp, but at your own risk.